# how can I realign <li> tag position?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Ok so here we have this `<nav>`element, as it's seen, I've inserted a `<svg>`, that's ok, but my problem is that the first `<li>` leaves a whitespace too large, but it happened after putting the `<svg>`, how can I realign the `<li>` without touching the others in the CSS styles?

```css
nav {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, indigo, darkgreen, indigo);
    font-family: simpsonfont;
}

.menu {
    display: block;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.menu li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.menu li a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover,.menu li:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
}

.menu ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: translate(0,20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu ul:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    color: #797979;
    background: yellow;
    text-indent: 16px;
}

.menu ul li a:hover,.menu ul li:hover>a {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}

.menu ul ul {
    left: 149px;
    top: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(20px,20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.menu ul ul:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 10%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

.menu li>ul ul:hover {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0,0);
}

.responsive-menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    background: #374147;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.responsive-menu:hover {
    background: #374147;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a class="responsive-menu" href="#" id="resp-menu"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i> Menu</a>    
   <ul class="menu">
<li><a class="homer" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> HOME</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
<li>
    <div> <svg fill="#ff0000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50" filter="invert(42%) sepia(93%) saturate(1352%) hue-rotate(87deg) brightness(119%) contrast(119%)" style="
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    transform: translate(0px, 45px);
"><path d="M 23 3 C 22.085938 3 21.621094 3.484375 21.058594 3.976563 C 20.496094 4.46875 19.925781 5.085938 19.390625 5.703125 C 18.855469 6.324219 18.359375 6.949219 17.96875 7.441406 C 17.785156 7.675781 17.625 7.875 17.503906 8.03125 C 17.335938 8.015625 17.132813 7.996094 16.851563 7.953125 C 16.167969 7.84375 15.230469 7.667969 14.238281 7.492188 C 13.246094 7.316406 12.203125 7.136719 11.257813 7.03125 C 10.3125 6.925781 9.519531 6.851563 8.773438 7.023438 C 8.410156 7.109375 8.125 7.390625 8.03125 7.75 C 7.476563 9.898438 7.683594 12.660156 7.984375 15.792969 C 7.910156 15.855469 7.824219 15.9375 7.664063 16.050781 C 7.25 16.34375 6.621094 16.710938 5.980469 17.089844 C 5.339844 17.46875 4.683594 17.851563 4.140625 18.257813 C 3.871094 18.460938 3.625 18.664063 3.410156 18.925781 C 3.195313 19.1875 2.941406 19.566406 3.007813 20.117188 C 3.015625 20.183594 3.027344 20.246094 3.046875 20.3125 C 3.640625 22.125 4.988281 23.6875 6.171875 24.859375 C 7.0625 25.742188 7.730469 26.273438 8.078125 26.546875 C 8.03125 26.859375 8 27.175781 8 27.5 C 8 29.683594 9.089844 31.613281 10.75 32.796875 C 10.164063 33.335938 9.628906 33.785156 9.203125 34.148438 C 8.921875 34.386719 8.675781 34.601563 8.453125 34.867188 C 8.234375 35.132813 8 35.511719 8 36 C 8 37.359375 8.988281 38.492188 10.515625 39.417969 C 11.851563 40.226563 13.691406 40.832031 16 40.96875 C 16 41 16 41.03125 16 41.0625 C 16 41.0625 16.035156 41.753906 16.414063 42.46875 C 16.792969 43.179688 17.699219 43.988281 18.984375 43.996094 C 18.996094 44.027344 19.011719 44.0625 19.011719 44.066406 L 19 45.996094 C 18.992188 46.355469 19.179688 46.691406 19.492188 46.875 C 19.800781 47.058594 20.1875 47.058594 20.5 46.878906 C 20.8125 46.699219 21.003906 46.367188 21 46.003906 L 21.011719 44.003906 C 21.011719 43.980469 21.011719 43.953125 21.007813 43.925781 C 21.007813 43.925781 20.988281 43.484375 20.734375 43.023438 C 20.484375 42.5625 19.824219 42 19 42 C 18.417969 42 18.332031 41.816406 18.179688 41.53125 C 18.046875 41.28125 18.011719 41.046875 18.003906 40.984375 C 21.285156 40.941406 23.570313 40.722656 25.027344 40.484375 C 26.09375 40.3125 26.65625 40.15625 27 40.046875 C 27.035156 40.582031 27.484375 40.992188 28.023438 40.980469 C 28.558594 40.96875 28.992188 40.535156 29 40 C 29 37.402344 26.484375 36.125 26.484375 36.125 C 26.335938 36.042969 26.171875 35.996094 26.003906 35.996094 C 25.542969 35.988281 25.140625 36.296875 25.023438 36.742188 C 24.90625 37.1875 25.113281 37.65625 25.515625 37.875 C 25.515625 37.875 25.738281 38.03125 25.988281 38.25 C 25.695313 38.324219 25.335938 38.410156 24.707031 38.515625 C 23.226563 38.753906 20.777344 39 17 39 C 14.535156 39 12.710938 38.410156 11.546875 37.703125 C 10.46875 37.050781 10.101563 36.308594 10.046875 36.09375 C 10.132813 36 10.273438 35.863281 10.5 35.671875 C 11 35.246094 11.78125 34.628906 12.675781 33.734375 C 13.003906 33.832031 13.34375 33.898438 13.6875 33.941406 C 14.109375 34.554688 14.703125 35 15.5 35 L 17 35 C 17.359375 35.003906 17.695313 34.816406 17.878906 34.503906 C 18.058594 34.191406 18.058594 33.808594 17.878906 33.496094 C 17.695313 33.183594 17.359375 32.996094 17 33 L 15.5 33 C 15.21875 33 15 32.78125 15 32.5 C 15 32.21875 15.21875 32 15.5 32 L 19.5 32 C 19.597656 32 19.695313 31.988281 19.789063 31.960938 C 20.976563 33.210938 22.648438 34 24.5 34 C 27.671875 34 30.320313 31.703125 30.886719 28.691406 C 30.917969 28.699219 30.929688 28.699219 30.960938 28.707031 C 31.34375 28.820313 31.652344 28.9375 31.652344 28.9375 C 32.167969 29.128906 32.746094 28.867188 32.9375 28.351563 C 33.128906 27.832031 32.867188 27.253906 32.347656 27.0625 C 32.347656 27.0625 31.988281 26.929688 31.535156 26.792969 C 31.347656 26.734375 31.140625 26.679688 30.933594 26.628906 C 30.847656 25.988281 30.667969 25.375 30.40625 24.808594 C 30.5625 24.648438 30.75 24.472656 30.921875 24.324219 C 31.277344 24.027344 31.574219 23.816406 31.574219 23.816406 C 31.929688 23.574219 32.089844 23.132813 31.972656 22.71875 C 31.855469 22.304688 31.488281 22.011719 31.058594 21.992188 C 31.023438 21.992188 30.988281 21.992188 30.957031 21.992188 C 30.765625 22.003906 30.582031 22.070313 30.425781 22.183594 C 30.425781 22.183594 30.0625 22.4375 29.640625 22.792969 C 29.523438 22.886719 29.398438 23.007813 29.28125 23.113281 C 28.851563 22.648438 28.359375 22.246094 27.8125 21.921875 C 28.28125 21.148438 28.714844 20.703125 28.714844 20.703125 C 29.007813 20.410156 29.089844 19.972656 28.929688 19.59375 C 28.765625 19.214844 28.386719 18.976563 27.972656 18.988281 C 27.710938 19 27.464844 19.109375 27.285156 19.296875 C 27.285156 19.296875 26.605469 20.019531 25.953125 21.171875 C 25.484375 21.0625 25 21 24.5 21 C 24.363281 21 24.226563 21.015625 24.09375 21.023438 C 24.035156 20.789063 23.976563 20.492188 23.964844 20.203125 C 23.941406 19.613281 23.996094 19.105469 23.996094 19.105469 C 24.027344 18.820313 23.9375 18.535156 23.746094 18.320313 C 23.554688 18.105469 23.28125 17.984375 22.992188 17.984375 C 22.480469 17.992188 22.054688 18.382813 22.003906 18.894531 C 22.003906 18.894531 21.9375 19.527344 21.96875 20.28125 C 21.980469 20.65625 21.996094 21.0625 22.082031 21.480469 C 21.074219 21.886719 20.183594 22.535156 19.496094 23.363281 C 19.359375 23.199219 19.210938 23.039063 19.058594 22.890625 C 19.242188 22.1875 19.679688 21.734375 19.679688 21.734375 C 19.988281 21.457031 20.09375 21.023438 19.945313 20.636719 C 19.800781 20.25 19.433594 19.992188 19.019531 19.988281 C 18.757813 19.988281 18.507813 20.085938 18.320313 20.265625 C 18.320313 20.265625 17.757813 20.785156 17.359375 21.671875 C 16.582031 21.289063 15.71875 21.0625 14.808594 21.015625 C 14.71875 20.523438 14.648438 19.894531 14.875 19.484375 C 15.054688 19.171875 15.050781 18.789063 14.867188 18.480469 C 14.6875 18.171875 14.351563 17.984375 13.996094 17.988281 C 13.628906 17.992188 13.296875 18.195313 13.125 18.515625 C 12.582031 19.5 12.609375 20.503906 12.746094 21.25 C 12.144531 21.417969 11.578125 21.671875 11.0625 22 C 11.03125 21.996094 10.945313 21.980469 10.734375 21.851563 C 10.488281 21.699219 10.171875 21.429688 9.957031 20.714844 C 9.835938 20.28125 9.4375 19.984375 8.992188 19.984375 C 8.671875 19.988281 8.375 20.140625 8.1875 20.398438 C 8 20.652344 7.949219 20.984375 8.042969 21.285156 C 8.351563 22.308594 8.917969 22.984375 9.46875 23.390625 C 9.191406 23.734375 8.945313 24.105469 8.742188 24.5 C 8.402344 24.214844 8.011719 23.867188 7.578125 23.4375 C 6.605469 22.472656 5.625 21.195313 5.140625 20.03125 C 5.207031 19.972656 5.238281 19.933594 5.339844 19.859375 C 5.738281 19.558594 6.359375 19.1875 6.992188 18.8125 C 7.628906 18.4375 8.28125 18.066406 8.816406 17.6875 C 9.085938 17.496094 9.324219 17.308594 9.542969 17.070313 C 9.761719 16.832031 10.054688 16.496094 9.996094 15.90625 C 9.71875 13.042969 9.640625 10.671875 9.90625 8.992188 C 10.25 8.984375 10.496094 8.957031 11.03125 9.015625 C 11.890625 9.117188 12.910156 9.285156 13.886719 9.460938 C 14.863281 9.636719 15.800781 9.8125 16.546875 9.929688 C 16.917969 9.984375 17.238281 10.027344 17.527344 10.046875 C 17.667969 10.054688 17.800781 10.058594 17.964844 10.042969 C 18.125 10.023438 18.347656 10.066406 18.707031 9.707031 C 18.855469 9.558594 18.917969 9.464844 19.050781 9.296875 C 19.183594 9.132813 19.347656 8.921875 19.539063 8.679688 C 19.917969 8.199219 20.402344 7.597656 20.90625 7.015625 C 21.40625 6.429688 21.9375 5.867188 22.375 5.480469 C 22.699219 5.199219 23.015625 5.074219 23.0625 5.027344 C 23.125 5.050781 23.214844 5.101563 23.375 5.234375 C 23.636719 5.445313 23.980469 5.820313 24.367188 6.28125 C 25.136719 7.210938 26.085938 8.5 27.292969 9.707031 C 27.609375 10.023438 28.101563 10.09375 28.492188 9.871094 C 28.492188 9.871094 30.226563 8.890625 32.058594 8.042969 C 32.972656 7.617188 33.917969 7.230469 34.625 7.019531 C 34.941406 6.925781 35.183594 6.882813 35.347656 6.867188 C 35.367188 6.910156 35.351563 6.871094 35.371094 6.933594 C 35.441406 7.148438 35.515625 7.464844 35.578125 7.832031 C 35.707031 8.566406 35.800781 9.511719 35.863281 10.433594 C 35.992188 12.269531 36 14.003906 36 14.003906 C 36 14.460938 36.3125 14.859375 36.757813 14.96875 C 36.757813 14.96875 38.476563 15.402344 40.175781 15.980469 C 41.027344 16.265625 41.875 16.597656 42.449219 16.890625 C 42.683594 17.015625 42.828125 17.117188 42.9375 17.199219 C 42.902344 17.308594 42.828125 17.683594 42.601563 18.253906 C 42.332031 18.9375 41.964844 19.757813 41.59375 20.542969 C 40.855469 22.113281 40.113281 23.535156 40.113281 23.535156 C 39.878906 23.988281 40.019531 24.542969 40.4375 24.828125 C 40.4375 24.828125 41.671875 25.664063 42.882813 26.675781 C 43.488281 27.183594 44.085938 27.734375 44.488281 28.207031 C 44.78125 28.550781 44.914063 28.867188 44.96875 28.957031 C 44.914063 29.035156 44.785156 29.28125 44.503906 29.546875 C 44.105469 29.921875 43.519531 30.351563 42.929688 30.734375 C 41.746094 31.507813 40.550781 32.105469 40.550781 32.105469 C 40.105469 32.328125 39.894531 32.847656 40.050781 33.316406 C 40.050781 33.316406 40.40625 34.371094 40.699219 35.492188 C 40.847656 36.054688 40.976563 36.632813 41.042969 37.066406 C 41.058594 37.195313 41.058594 37.265625 41.066406 37.359375 C 40.984375 37.386719 40.929688 37.410156 40.816406 37.4375 C 40.390625 37.542969 39.796875 37.648438 39.214844 37.734375 C 38.046875 37.90625 36.910156 38.003906 36.910156 38.003906 C 36.488281 38.042969 36.132813 38.34375 36.03125 38.757813 L 35.328125 41.550781 C 34.523438 41.199219 33.472656 40.757813 32.71875 40.269531 C 32.753906 40.132813 32.796875 39.949219 32.824219 39.863281 C 33.109375 39.835938 33.167969 39.886719 33.5625 39.75 C 34.421875 39.449219 35.488281 38.703125 35.949219 37.316406 C 36.378906 36.027344 36.191406 34.8125 35.515625 34.042969 C 34.839844 33.273438 33.882813 33 33 33 C 31.171875 33 30.171875 34.4375 30.171875 34.4375 C 29.964844 34.734375 29.933594 35.121094 30.089844 35.445313 C 30.246094 35.769531 30.566406 35.984375 30.925781 36.007813 C 31.285156 36.035156 31.628906 35.863281 31.828125 35.5625 C 31.828125 35.5625 32.179688 35 33 35 C 33.441406 35 33.839844 35.160156 34.011719 35.359375 C 34.183594 35.558594 34.332031 35.84375 34.050781 36.683594 C 33.792969 37.453125 33.359375 37.703125 32.902344 37.863281 C 32.441406 38.023438 32.066406 38 32.066406 38 C 31.605469 37.96875 31.179688 38.261719 31.042969 38.707031 C 31.042969 38.707031 30 42.109375 30 46 C 29.996094 46.359375 30.183594 46.695313 30.496094 46.878906 C 30.808594 47.058594 31.191406 47.058594 31.503906 46.878906 C 31.816406 46.695313 32.003906 46.359375 32 46 C 32 44.597656 32.136719 43.363281 32.296875 42.339844 C 33.789063 43.1875 35.625 43.925781 35.625 43.925781 C 35.890625 44.035156 36.195313 44.023438 36.453125 43.890625 C 36.710938 43.761719 36.898438 43.523438 36.96875 43.242188 L 37.800781 39.910156 C 38.222656 39.871094 38.632813 39.839844 39.503906 39.714844 C 40.125 39.621094 40.757813 39.511719 41.300781 39.375 C 41.574219 39.308594 41.824219 39.238281 42.0625 39.136719 C 42.300781 39.035156 42.5625 38.976563 42.84375 38.535156 C 43.089844 38.148438 43.078125 37.871094 43.082031 37.597656 C 43.089844 37.328125 43.0625 37.0625 43.019531 36.78125 C 42.9375 36.210938 42.789063 35.585938 42.632813 34.984375 C 42.425781 34.195313 42.316406 33.890625 42.183594 33.472656 C 42.628906 33.238281 43.089844 33.019531 44.019531 32.414063 C 44.671875 31.992188 45.332031 31.515625 45.878906 31 C 46.425781 30.480469 46.960938 29.949219 47 29.042969 C 47.039063 28.097656 46.53125 27.519531 46.003906 26.90625 C 45.480469 26.289063 44.820313 25.691406 44.167969 25.140625 C 43.214844 24.34375 42.707031 24.011719 42.265625 23.703125 C 42.511719 23.222656 42.832031 22.609375 43.40625 21.394531 C 43.785156 20.585938 44.167969 19.734375 44.460938 18.984375 C 44.753906 18.238281 45 17.710938 45 17 C 45 16.378906 44.648438 16.015625 44.359375 15.761719 C 44.066406 15.503906 43.734375 15.308594 43.363281 15.113281 C 42.625 14.730469 41.722656 14.390625 40.824219 14.082031 C 39.390625 13.597656 38.492188 13.378906 37.972656 13.246094 C 37.964844 12.722656 37.964844 11.824219 37.859375 10.296875 C 37.796875 9.335938 37.699219 8.339844 37.550781 7.484375 C 37.476563 7.058594 37.386719 6.667969 37.269531 6.3125 C 37.15625 5.953125 37.039063 5.625 36.707031 5.292969 C 36.25 4.835938 35.738281 4.828125 35.324219 4.851563 C 34.90625 4.875 34.496094 4.972656 34.058594 5.101563 C 33.175781 5.363281 32.179688 5.78125 31.21875 6.226563 C 29.675781 6.945313 28.761719 7.464844 28.246094 7.75 C 27.394531 6.824219 26.601563 5.84375 25.90625 5.007813 C 25.492188 4.503906 25.09375 4.054688 24.652344 3.6875 C 24.207031 3.324219 23.671875 3 23 3 Z M 30 46 C 30 45.449219 29.550781 45 29 45 C 28.449219 45 28 45.449219 28 46 C 28 46.550781 28.449219 47 29 47 C 29.550781 47 30 46.550781 30 46 Z M 14.5 23 C 16.179688 23 17.628906 23.921875 18.402344 25.277344 C 18.148438 25.972656 18 26.71875 18 27.5 C 18 28.386719 18.179688 29.230469 18.5 30 L 15.5 30 C 14.386719 30 13.445313 30.75 13.125 31.765625 C 11.3125 31.1875 10 29.515625 10 27.5 C 10 25.15625 11.773438 23.269531 14.054688 23.046875 C 14.101563 23.042969 14.144531 23.039063 14.1875 23.03125 C 14.292969 23.023438 14.394531 23 14.5 23 Z M 24.5 23 C 26.964844 23 28.941406 24.957031 28.988281 27.410156 C 28.984375 27.46875 28.984375 27.53125 28.988281 27.59375 C 28.941406 30.042969 26.964844 32 24.5 32 C 22.003906 32 20 29.996094 20 27.5 C 20 25.003906 22.003906 23 24.5 23 Z M 13 27 C 12.449219 27 12 27.449219 12 28 C 12 28.550781 12.449219 29 13 29 C 13.550781 29 14 28.550781 14 28 C 14 27.449219 13.550781 27 13 27 Z M 25 27 C 24.449219 27 24 27.449219 24 28 C 24 28.550781 24.449219 29 25 29 C 25.550781 29 26 28.550781 26 28 C 26 27.449219 25.550781 27 25 27 Z M 23 45 C 22.449219 45 22 45.449219 22 46 C 22 46.550781 22.449219 47 23 47 C 23.550781 47 24 46.550781 24 46 C 24 45.449219 23.550781 45 23 45 Z M 26 45 C 25.449219 45 25 45.449219 25 46 C 25 46.550781 25.449219 47 26 47 C 26.550781 47 27 46.550781 27 46 C 27 45.449219 26.550781 45 26 45 Z"></path></svg>
        <a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></div></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> PORTFOLIO</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub Sub-Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> BLOG</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these classes

```
.menu ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 58px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: translate(0,20px);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

another inside menu ->li ->div

```
.menu li div{
    margin-top: -32px;
}
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vahid_634/7mvszyjn/)

Comment: I'll give it a go Vahid, thanx

Comment: @FedericoMigueletto if answer is helpful for you, please accept/vote for this

Comment: yes @VahidAkhar, it's helpful and functional, take your upvote; thanks and happy new year!

Comment: @FedericoMigueletto thanks and same to you....Have a great year.